# An iterator of iterators?

Tags: r, iterator

Is there a way to store iterators as elements of a wrapping iterator? For example:

```
iterOfIter <- function() {
  L <- list()
  for ( n in seq(1,5) ) {
    L <- append( L, iter( c(1,2,3) ) )
  }
  iter(L)
}
```

doesn't produce an error, but when it is run produces:

```
> ii <- iterOfIter()
> i <- nextElem(ii)
> nextElem(i)
Error in UseMethod("nextElem") : 
  no applicable method for 'nextElem' applied to an object of class    "environment"
> class(i)
[1] "environment"
```

Ideally, I would like to call:

```
> ii <- iterOfIter()
> i <- nextElem(ii)
> nextElem(i)
[1] 1
> nextElem(i)
[1] 2
> nextElem(i)
[1] 3
> i <- nextElem(ii)
> nextElem(i)
[1] 1
... and so on.
```

Comment: Did you meant `iter(seq_along(L))`

Comment: Thank you for responding, but that doesn't seem to work, either. I get the following error: `> ii <- iterOfIter(); > i <- nextElem(ii); > nextElem(i)
Error in UseMethod("nextElem") : 
  no applicable method for 'nextElem' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"`

Comment: Not for me.  I was able to get the expected output.  I meant to replace the `iter(L)` with `iter(seq_along(L))` in the function

Comment: Interesting. Please post your code. I have tried every option and variation I can think of, but it appears that (for me) the iterator stored in the list is "unrolled" when it gets appended. When I call "nextElem" on the result of "iterOfIters" I get an integer, not an iterator. I'm running R version 3.4.0. Could that make a difference?